# mysql Alter table to add column with selected

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I am trying to use ALTER to add a new column (authorID) to the tests table, but I want to have a specific value (which I don't know).

I am trying to run the following, but getting SQL errors.  Is this possible, if so where have I gone wrong please?

```
SELECT id FROM authors WHERE emailAddress = 'UNASSIGNED' into @unassignedID;
ALTER TABLE Tests ADD COLUMN authorID INT NOT NULL DEFAULT @unassignedID;
```

Authors table:

```
CREATE TABLE authors
(
  ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  emailAddress VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  regionID INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

Tests Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Tests
(
  testID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Title VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY(testID)
);
```

Comment: No, it does not work like that. After the alter table you need an insert or an update (depending on whether you have records in the test table). If you need insert, then use `insert ... select ... instead`. You also cannot retrieve a list a results into a session variable like this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `prepared` `statement`:

```
SELECT id into @unassignedID   FROM authors  WHERE emailAddress = 'UNASSIGNED' limit 1; 
SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE Tests  ADD COLUMN authorID INT NOT NULL DEFAULT ',@unassignedID);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```